# SpecFlow "Generate Test Definition" context menu missing in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, specflow, dnx

I'm trying out VS2015 and writing SpecFlow feature files. When I right click on the file, I cannot find "Generate Test Definitions" context menu. This happens only in "Class Library (Package)" which is obviously DNX 5.0 library.

Here is my project.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [ "" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",

    "dependencies": {
        "SpecFlow": "1.9.0",
        "SpecFlow.xUnit": "1.0.2",
        "xunit": "2.1.0-beta3-build3029",
        "xunit.extensions": "2.0.0"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
            "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
            "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
            "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have added SpecFlow Visual Studio 2015 extensions.

Am I missing something here?

But if I try the same in a normal Class Library that works fine.

Comment: with the normal class library, the test explorer does not list the test cases. another problem !

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that SpecFlow is only supported on classic DotNet framework applications, the dnx format is too new/unstable to be fully supported yet.

Looking at http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Visual-Studio-2015-Integration/ gives hints that this integration may not be complete. (I note NuGet said the same thing only a few months ago http://blog.nuget.org/20150331/nuget-2.8.5.html).

Sorry this is all guess work.

You might want to raise this as an issue with them, https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues.

Comment: I suspect that this is right. Its all still a bit new to expect full support yet. PR welcome though.

Answer (score 4):

I found this little gem to provide a good bridge until Specflow sorts out this issue:

https://github.com/stajs/SpecFlow.Dnx

Be sure to read the ReadMe file!

Comment: Thats meeeeeeeeeeee! =)

Comment: Now [updated for .NET Core](https://github.com/stajs/SpecFlow.NetCore).

Answer (score 0):

From SpecFlow documentation:

*Right-click on your specification project (e.g. “MyProject.Specs”) and select Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.
Search for “SpecRun” and install SpecRun.SpecFlow.*

I made these steps and received 'Generate Step Definition' button. :)