# SpecFlow + ASP.Net 5 (DNX)

Tags: asp.net, specflow, dnx50

We created an application containing several projects in the new DNX-format.
We've added a unittestproject, which is not DNX-format.

We are using SpecFlow to create some tests.
In the unittestproject we added the necessary references to work with specflow.
We are able to generate the test-steps from the feature-file.

However when we want to add a references in our unittestproject to our domainlayer-project, which is a DN-format, we keep getting the message that we cannot reference it.

What are we doing wrong?

We also tried adding a testproject in dnx-format but then we couldn't get the SpecFlow working.

Comment: I don't think specflow will support DNX projects yet

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182052/specflow-generate-test-definition-context-menu-missing-in-vs2015) which implies there is a bridging library you can use